# NPM: Registry is missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/n

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: n
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:209:10)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.<anonymous> (http.js:1137:11)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /var/www/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-58-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "n"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: n
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/www/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

I was trying to update the nodejs installation but i couldn't.

I followed the steps [here](http://theholmesoffice.com/node-js-fundamentals-how-to-upgrade-the-node-js-version/).

Comment: Try upgrading Node using your OS package manager.

Comment: i did that already, it was a fresh install..

Comment: Are you on Ubuntu? I think it’s about the only distribution left with a horribly out-of-date version of Node in its default set of repositories. You could try compiling it from source or grabbing one of those PPA things. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7214700/707111

Comment: Then again, if you’d like to use n, go ahead and grab it at https://github.com/visionmedia/n/blob/master/bin/n.

Comment: how can i install it via npm?

Comment: You apparently can’t, so download the file I linked to from GitHub and run it. `bash n`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i have answered my own question.

Aparently `sudo apt-get install nodejs` directly from the repository would only give you a maximum of v.0.06.

So what i did was the following

```
https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/
```

i added the PPA, then did the whole install nodejs again.

Afterwhich, the version is now v.0.10

Hope this would help anyone in my case.