# 404 error while trying to install nodejs in ubunutu

Tags: node.js

I am getting the following error message while trying to install nodejs:

```
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libc-ares2 amd64 1.9.1-3  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]    
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/universe nodejs amd64 0.6.19~dfsg1-5ubuntu1 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/c-ares/libc-ares2_1.9.1-3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/nodejs/nodejs_0.6.19~dfsg1-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
```

I had used the command:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Has anybody faced this problem before ?

Comment: Did you search first?  You need to use a ppa - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214474/how-to-keep-up-with-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-in-ubuntu-ppa-compiling

Comment: that server's either got an incomplete mirror of the ubuntu archives, or is no longer an archive at all, or is misconfigured.

Comment: all else fails, building from source is really easy. 

download tarball, extract, cd into, `./config`, `make`, `sudo make install`

Answer (score 0):

You should use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/ubuntu/node.js) to keep node up-to-date with the latest stable version. The Ubuntu/Debian repositories have node also, but they are not regularly updated and sometimes contain very outdated versions.

As @MarcB pointed out, the particular mirror you are currently using [does not support quantal](http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/).

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash
```

from their documentation https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Answer (score 0):

Update the package list first with `sudo apt-get update`.
Then run `sudo apt-get install nodejs` again.

Answer (score -1):

try out the following commands with the given key

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 68576280
sudo apt-add-repository "deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x $(lsb_release -sc) main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

The above mention code is for getting NodeJs version 7

for different versions you can check out the github page of nodesource (who maintains PPAs of nodejs) `https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall`